# Sending a mail to gmail using mercury server in XAMPP in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, email

I need to send a mail to gmail from local mail server Mercury in XAMPP.I configured it.I wrote a java program to send a mail using JavaMail API.When i run it it shows that it sent.But,I didn't receive any mail in gmail.

Following is the code got it from internet

```
import java.util.Properties;  
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  

public class SendMailBySite {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  

String host="127.0.0.1";  
final String user="root@localhost.com";//change accordingly  
final String password="root";//change accordingly  

String to="kishorejohnsan.s@gmail.com";//change accordingly  

//Get the session object  
Properties props = new Properties();  
props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
   }  
});  

//Compose the message  
try {  
 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
 message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
 message.setSubject("javatpoint");  
 message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");  

//send the message  
 Transport.send(message);  

 System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  

 } catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
}  
}
```

Anyone pls correct me.

Comment: This is only java code I'll later convert it into jsp/servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your smpt server configuration to this and take the Google's gmail smtp server to use:

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
final String user="kishorejohnsan.s@gmail.com"; 
final String password="your gmail account password";//change accordingly  

String to = "kishorejohnsan.s@gmail.com";//change accordingly
//Get the session object
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
```

Comment: Thank you @FrAn the code works fine... and i received mail.